# How to convert JSON to plain text using gateway script in API Connect

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to convert JSON data to plain text.

```
apim.readInputAsJSON(function (error,buffer) 
  if (error) {  
    console.log("Failed to read data in JSON format"); 
  } else { 
    var res = JSON.stringify(buffer);session.output.write(res);    
    apim.output('text/plain');  
  }
});
```

but I am getting JSON out instead of text format

```
{ "hubChallenge": "Done"}
```

Comment: What is the output you'd like to see?

Comment: I guess, the function `readInputAsJSON` is called like that for a reason? Because it returns JSON perhaps? It's up to you to parse that JSON data and display it as you need

Comment: @ControlAltDel I am expecting "Done" in the response.

Comment: @ManduriTeja 'm note sure, how exactly setting output with `apim.output('text/plain')` format your text. But in this case, when you need just one property, it seems no problem to keep your output as JSON and print just the value with `res.hubChallenge`

Comment: also it seems you are setting format of your output `apim.output('text/plain')` **after** the output `session.output.write(res)`

Comment: @LudovitMydla I already tired in the first case by giving res.hubChallenge, when I am giving it I am getting "undefined" as a response.

Comment: Post some logs/ try to debug it step by step. It doesn't seem like it should be a big problem. Maybe some typo or different variable type then expected. Since once you were able to get JSON object, there shouldn't be a problem to access it

Comment: I don't what exactly causing the issue, but if I am have response as {
 "data": {
   "moves": "slow"
 },
 "height": "7",
 "name": "bulbasaur",
 "weight": 69,
 "id": 1,
 "base_experience": 64
} I am able to get data as expected. If I am having single key value pair I am getting "undefined" as response using as code.

Comment: GIve us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise, we're unable to help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
apim.readInputAsJSON(function (error,buffer) 
{   if (error) {  
console.log("Failed to read data in JSON format"); 
 }else { 
var res = JSON.stringify(buffer);session.output.write(buffer.hubChallenge || res.hubChallenge);    
 apim.output('text/plain');  }});
```